# Writing a macro to paste a range in every 26th row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying an array (Sheet1!A2:A831) and want to paste it on Sheet2! in every 26th row starting at A1.

I was working with this macro, but I'm having some trouble:

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("Sheet1!A2:A831").Copy
For i = 26 To LR Step 26
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you copying an 800-odd row range and then pasting it every 26 rows?

Comment: Just organizing SEO content. Each 26 rows I begin a new product. I have 830 products.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A831").Copy` If you just use `Range()` without qualifying it with a worksheet, then it defaults to a range on the ActiveSheet (and there's no range from sheet1 on sheet2...)

Comment: Which result do you expect? Do you really want to overwrite all of the previously pasted cells with every new paste operation except the first 26?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, n As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        n = 1

        For i = 2 To LR 'A2:A831
            .Range("A" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & n).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

            n = n + 25
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```